# AngularJS - Is it possible to pass attr value in Directive link function directly to template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was wondering if its possible to access attrs that were passed into a custom directive directly within the template config? So something like this... which currently isn't working?

```
angular.module('msDirectives', [])
    .directive('msPerson', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            },
            template: '<h1>{{attrs.firstName}}</h1>',
        };
    });
```

I realize I could assign attrs.firstName to scope within the link function to get this to work (like the following), just trying to understand whether scope is the only thing accessible within the template or whether attrs also get passed to it.

```
angular.module('msDirectives', [])
    .directive('msPerson', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.name = attrs.firstName;
            },
            template: '<h1>{{name}}</h1>'
        };
    });
```

Comment: You can always do `scope.attrs = attrs`.

Comment: So does that mean scope is the only thin that is passed to the template. attrs are never passed to the template automatically?

Comment: Angular expressions and directives (in the template or otherwise) are always linked against some scope - nothing else. Then you can bind against the properties of a scope. Some properties are automatically set on the scope, like the alias in ControllerAs, or some library/directive might pass some "locals"... but at the end of the day it is just a property of the scope. Specifically, `$scope.attrs` is not automatically set.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of isolated scope (besides the isolation itself) is the assignment of attribute values to scope.

```
angular.module('msDirectives', [])
    .directive('msPerson', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name: '@firstName'
            },
            template: '<h1>{{name}}</h1>'
        };
    });
```

Comment: So does that mean scope is the only thin that is passed to the template. attrs are never passed to the template automatically?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's it. The most common way to do this is via isolated scope, and you have to assign attribute values from `attrs` to scope in controller/link manually (if you can't use isolated scope for some reason).